# Ember JS IndexedDB adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I notice that there has been some work done on an indexedDB adapter for Ember Data.

https://github.com/panayi/ember-data-indexeddb-adapter

I have tried to use it at revision 11, and it does not seem to work.

The js error I get is:

> Object in path router.store.adapter could not be found or was destroyed.

Does anybody know anything about this adapter and if there is to be any more work on it.

Comment: the fact that there haven't really been any updates since the initial commit 4 months ago doesn't bode well.

Comment: l33z3r, @FinnMacCool see comment here https://github.com/panayi/ember-data-indexeddb-adapter/issues/1

Comment: Ok, thanks, really looking forward to getting this repo up to date to work with the latest revision of ember data :)

Comment: I have tried to use the indexeddb adapter with ember-data revision 7, but I just get the following error: `Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super` Any ideas?